# Which package should unrelated classes belong to in Java?

Tags: java, packages

In a project, certain related classes can be grouped together in one package. But some other useful classes are not related to any other class and so cannot be put into a package with any other classes.

A StackOverflow answer I read says that it isn't a bad practice to put such classes in their own packages (just one class in a package), but somehow I feel this is not the best way to go.

So in such situations, what should be done with these unrelated classes?

Comment: Are these classes used in any other application?  If they are, then they need to be in their own package.  Otherwise, put them where it's most convenient.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically they should go in a `util` or `misc` package. But for example if you have a class `DatabaseUtil` it can go directly under `db`, supposing there you also have subpackages `db.model`, `db.dao` etc. for other database related classes.

I don't find it at all suitable to have these classes each in its own package (that's not what packages are designed for).

Comment: While there are valid uses for "util" classes, often this is a code smell that something needs to be refactored.

Comment: @Snowman I strongly disagree; most libraries have such packages: JDK - `java.util.*`, Spring Core - `org.springframework.util.*`, Guava - `com.google.common.util.*`.

Comment: I am not talking about packages, I am talking about classes. `java.util` for example contains reusable classes, not classes with static methods. The reason for util classes often is to provide useful functions on objects such as `String` where you are not able to modify the class and it is missing important functionality.

Comment: There are plenty of `*Utils` or `*s` classes just with static methods in the libraries: in JDK: `Objects`, `Collections`, `Executors` etc.; in Spring: `RefelectionUtils`, `ClassUtils` etc.

Comment: If the core classes had been thought out better, those would not be needed. They are a necessary evil because the core Java classes do not do enough. My argument is that if you are writing util classes for your own classes, take those static methods and make them instance methods of the classes on which they operate.

Comment: @Snowman Although I get your point, there are plenty of use cases where purely OOP cannot be achieved like for example actions on whole Collections but depending on elements types, operations with callbacks etc.